# Ubuntu 17.10 hang while running as VM on ESXi 6.5

Tags: 17.10, vmware, esx

I have a question regarding running Ubuntu 17.10 (with `open-vm-tools`) as a VM on ESXi. I installed ESXi on my PC then install Ubuntu 17.10 as my virtual machine. Below is a screenshot of my VM settings:

[image: VM configuration screenshot]

What my problem is, the ubuntu desktop will hang while:

1. Browsing some website using FireFox (I tried Chrome but same result). I'm not sure if that is randomly but I tried to restore all sessions, then desktop will hang again.
2. If I leave the machine idle, after a few hours the same will happen.
3. After this issue happens, even `ping` is not able to reach the VM.

**Symptoms:**

1. Cursor is working, but not able to click on anything.
2. The system clock is freezed on the hang time.
3. `ping` test to virtual machine will show not able to reach to host.

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to increase the total memory on VM settings, but it doesn't help.
2. I tried to cat the logs under `/var/log/syslog` but no luck, there is no error captured during that period. Please refer to below screenshot (I reboot the machine at 11AM).

   [image: Capture from syslog]

Anyone knows more about this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried Alt+SysRq+b while the VM freezes but nothing happen. If the VM is normal then it will restart by sending this command. For VT I tried but seems nothing happen on my VM.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems and installed the U1 update to solve them.

I followed [this update procedure](https://miketabor.com/how-to-update-vmware-esxi-6-5-to-6-5-update-1/).

Summary:

```
esxcli network firewall ruleset set -e true -r httpClient
esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-6.5.0-20170702001-standard
esxcli network firewall ruleset set -e false -r httpClient
reboot
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing!!! It does help a lot. I updated the ESXi and I will monitor for a few days than rate your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: After monitored for a few days the linux is working well. Many thanks for your help again.